# Problems with dual screen in awesome

Tags: multiple-monitors, awesome

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on an late 2010 MacBook in order to use it lid-closed  with a big screen and to use it with awesome. I activted both screens with the `nvidia-settings` tool. Awesome starts two seperate instances of the window manager. We want the external monitor to be the main screen and I dont need another instance of awesome on my laptop monitor. It seems like the awesome instance on my external screen does not run all the commands as the instance on the laptop screen because the fonts in GTK-Applications are really small. And the font Monospace in the Terminal looks completely different (not that smooth) on the external monitor.

This is the output of `xrandr -q` on my laptop screen awesome instance

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 175, current 1280 x 800, maximum 1280 x 800
default connected 1280x800+0+0 0mm x 0mm
1280x800       50.0* 
1024x768       51.0     52.0
...
```

and on my external screen awesome instace

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 1: minimum 320 x 175, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080      50.0*    51.0  
   1680x1050      52.0     53.0
...
```

How do I deactivte the laptop screen and make the external screen my one and only awesome instance which displays the fonts nicely? Is it even possible to this lid-closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simply not to use the `nvidia`-drivers but the `noveau`-drivers because they support xrandr.